# Is there a way to get ALL packages and dependencies of Go programs in a given directory and its subdirectories using Go standard tooling?

Tags: go, dependencies

I have a large directory of Go packages which is actually my $GOPATH/src directory. I am trying to get a list of all packages (and their versions eventually if possible, but even names would be a nice start) within all subdirectories of that directory recursively (including the vendor directories). When I run `go list all ./...` in $GOPATH/src, I get a bunch of messages saying:

> code in directory [foo] expects import [bar]

However, if I navigate to the individual package working directories, it seems to work. I am also not sure why it actually does find the packages in the above command, but displays that error, which it does not display when I navigate down to each package's directory. Is there a way to specify such a recursive lookup using the Go toolset?

Answer (score 0):

> I am also not sure why it actually does find the packages in the above command, but displays that error, which it does not display when I navigate down to each package's directory

That seems to be the consequence of [`src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/519c0a2323700934cbec97b75df92917108548be/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L910-L914)

```golang
        if !cfg.ModulesEnabled && data.err == nil &&
            data.p.ImportComment != "" && data.p.ImportComment != path &&
            !strings.Contains(path, "/vendor/") && !strings.HasPrefix(path, "vendor/") {
            data.err = fmt.Errorf("code in directory %s expects import %q", data.p.Dir, data.p.ImportComment)
        }
```

In a non-module-enabled project, with `vendor/` packages, you would get that error (as opposed to the same command run *inside* the `vendor` folder, which would not trigger the condition shown above)